# Free Type path in OSX

Tags: c++, macos, freetype, freetype2

Where can I find the "ft2build.h" header file in my OSX 10.11 ? Currently when I try to build a project using include , it says that file not found. Any ideas ?

Comment: Do you have Freetype lib installed? Where? Are you using xcode? command-line?

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès - The only freetype lib I found is in /usr/X11R6/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib and Im using command line in building my project

Comment: Did you used a cflags to include header from that dir? Use `-I`path_to_the_dir_you_need

Comment: I still get file not found. Please see this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18887445/does-freetype-comes-pre-installed-on-mac), it says that I don't have the actual file that needs when compiling, I tried to look for the path in that answer but it does not exist in my laptop. Do i need to download freetype to make it work?

Comment: You gave me the path of the library, you have to find the path to the headers... If you have the lib, you probably have the headers. I can suggest you to have a look inside your xcode dev chain (gcc -v will help you).

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès - I get this path "Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1 but still no visible ft2build.h

Comment: Install `brew` and `freetype` package under brew.