# Error Installing Matplotlib on Python 3.8

Tags: python, matplotlib, terminal, macos-catalina, python-3.8

I currently have Python 2.7 and Python 3.8 (downloaded the .dmg via Python.org) on my Mac OS X Catalina. I have successfully installed Numpy via Terminal, as well as Matplotlib on Python 2.7 via Terminal, but I always get two error codes when I install Matplotlib through Terminal. I've tried using different variants of inputs via terminal via troubleshooting I did in my online research, but to no avail.

Input:

```
pip3 install matplotlib
```

Output (Error #1):

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3.8 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/6l/48hzctr50x9gg5rv9zzc5jl40000gn/T/pip-install-k3_jyhbb/matplotlib/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/6l/48hzctr50x9gg5rv9zzc5jl40000gn/T/pip-install-k3_jyhbb/matplotlib/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/6l/48hzctr50x9gg5rv9zzc5jl40000gn/T/pip-record-9nz4sjf0/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile
     cwd: /private/var/folders/6l/48hzctr50x9gg5rv9zzc5jl40000gn/T/pip-install-k3_jyhbb/matplotlib/
Complete output (509 lines):
IMPORTANT WARNING:
    pkg-config is not installed.
    matplotlib may not be able to find some of its dependencies
================================================================================
Edit setup.cfg to change the build options
```

Output (Error #2):

```
  gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DFREETYPE_BUILD_TYPE=system -DPY_ARRAY_UNIQUE_SYMBOL=MPL_matplotlib_ft2font_ARRAY_API -DNPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API=NPY_1_7_API_VERSION -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS=1 -Iextern/agg24-svn/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -c src/checkdep_freetype2.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/src/checkdep_freetype2.o
src/checkdep_freetype2.c:1:10: fatal error: 'ft2build.h' file not found
#include <ft2build.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3.8 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/6l/48hzctr50x9gg5rv9zzc5jl40000gn/T/pip-install-k3_jyhbb/matplotlib/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/6l/48hzctr50x9gg5rv9zzc5jl40000gn/T/pip-install-k3_jyhbb/matplotlib/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/6l/48hzctr50x9gg5rv9zzc5jl40000gn/T/pip-record-9nz4sjf0/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: The second error seems to indicate that you are missing the `ft2build` header. I think this is part of `freetype`, so I think you will need the `freetype` libraries to solve this second error. Maybe see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18887445/does-freetype-comes-pre-installed-on-mac

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this by using the unnoficial packages, you can download then [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#matplotlib) 
and just make sure to install de requirements, you can find them on the link too, then install each package with:

```
pip install "SomePackage-1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl"
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally found my resolution in a reddit comment by "Diapolo10" under topic "Error when installing matplotlib via pip". I was using 32-bit Python. I deleted it and installed 64-bit Python. Afterward, I was able to install the libraries without issue.

Answer (score -2):

> Installed matplotlib on python 2.7

The current version of matplotlib requires Python >= 3.6, so this might be part of your challenge. But I think the first error is where the issue lays - it looks like you're missing your needed 3rd party dependencies. You can get those here:
https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/users/installing.html#building-on-macos

Feel free to paste your output in a comment if that doesn't work.